# Drone - build based on branch

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, drone.io

I am using [Drone](https://drone.io) as my CI/CD tool and now I'm facing an issue with this. My team consists of developers and testers (who also are developers), and the Test Team wants to put a specific branch in the `staging` environment, to test everything before merge it. The issue is: **how to do that?**

Drone has many configurations that can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.drone.io/). I am searching for something that allows my team to enter a Job and specify the branch in some sort of Dropdown component, then run the Job using that branch. This can be done so easily with Jenkins. Is there any way of doing that in Drone?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Drone is very git-commit driven, which took some getting used to when we transitioned away from Jenkins.

You can probably do what you described with [promotions](https://docs.drone.io/promote/). Promotions let you re-run a previous build with specific parameters. This lets you run different pipeline steps, or even completely different pipelines, depending on the promotion target specified.

Comment: Amazing Jim, I'll try to implement and get back with news. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of promotions and triggers will get you where you need to go. Here is documentation on [triggers](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/trigger/) .

So I would create a promotion that is triggered by the 'staging' branch. You can also ask more questions in the [community slack for drone](https://join.slack.com/t/harnesscommunity/shared_invite/zt-90wb0w6u-OATJvUBkSDR3W9oYX7D%7E4A)